# OOP - Extendeding of classes OK, but functions are not overriding

Tags: wordpress, class, oop

I extended a parent theme class via child theme:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', function() {
class MyNewClass extends MyOldClass {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function output() { //this function exists also in MyOldClass, echoing $this->args[ 'before' ] . "What's Up?" . $this->args[ 'after' ];
        echo $this->args[ 'before' ] . "Hi There" . $this->args[ 'after' ];
    }
}
$theClass = new MyNewClass;
}, 42 );
```

But it does not override original **output()**.

If I do

```
echo($theClass->output());
```

It does print what I want (>> Hi There <<), just not in place.

Also the old output() is still running and the new one does not override it.

What's going on?

Comment: What action hook is `output` attached to in the original class?

Comment: Thanks for responding. This is the hook:

$crumbs = new MyOldClass( apply_filters( 'my_old_class', array(...some values...) );  $crumbs->output();

Comment: This code exists in another class that MyOldClass is an extension of.

Comment: I'm sorry. I think that this is what you asked:

In MyClassA parent class there is a function `public function setup_actions()` that contains `add_action( 'single_job_listing_meta_start', array( $this, 'the_category' ), 30 );`

And `the_category` is the function that contains 

`$crumbs = new MyOldClass( apply_filters( 'my_old_class', array(...some values...) ); $crumbs->output();`

Hope this helps =|

Comment: Tried to extend the parent class too but it doesn't override its functions either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
<?php 
class MyNewClass extends MyOldClass  {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( $this, 'return_output' ) );
    }
    public function return_output() { 
    //this function exists also in MyOldClass, echoing $this->args[ 'before' ] . "What's Up?" . $this->args[ 'after' ];
        echo $this->args[ 'before' ] . "Hi There" . $this->args[ 'after' ];
    }

}
$theClass = new MyNewClass;

echo $theClass->return_output();
?>
```

Or Proper way to write Hooks inside classes are explained here : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/